# Using S3 Versioning to Show Original Always

Tags: version-control, amazon-s3

Is there a way for me to set up an S3 bucket so that it keeps all of the versions of a file that are made, but displays the original by default? Amazon says:

> By default, GET requests will retrieve the most recently written version.

Where can I find the option to change that default, or is it impossible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible.  You can only get the latest version:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGET.html

Or you can enumerate all versions from newest to oldest:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGETVersion.html